# Using GridRecord Event Args

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to asp.net and I have a condition where when I click a button i need to use Gridrecord event args.

```
 protected void yesclicked(object sender, GridRecordEventArgs e)
{
    NCDCPoint ncdc = new NCDCPoint();

    SaveAllColumnFields(ref ncdc, e);
    mCDC.NCDCPoints.InsertOnSubmit(ncdc);
    mCDC.SubmitChanges();
    //do this after insert because it wont work until the ncdc object
    //has been assigned an ID
    SaveAllDynamicFields(mCDC, ref ncdc, e);
    mCDC.SubmitChanges();
    Grid1.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
    //SaveAllColumnFields(ref ncdc, e);
}
```

My grid mark up:

```
           <obout:Grid runat="server" ID="Grid1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="10" EnableRecordHover="True"
                Width="80%" AllowPaging="true" AllowManualPaging="true" AllowPageSizeSelection="false"
                CurrentPageIndex="0" OnInsertCommand="InsertRecord" OnDeleteCommand="DeleteRecord"
                OnUpdateCommand="UpdateRecord" EnableTypeValidation="false" OnRebind="RebindGrid"
                CallbackMode="true" Serialize="true" OnRowDataBound="Grid1_RowDataBound" AllowColumnReordering="true">
```

In .aspx age

```
       <obout:OboutButton ID="yesbutton" runat="server" Text="yes" OnClick="yesclicked"></obout:OboutButton>
       <obout:OboutButton ID="nobutton" runat="server" Text="no" OnClick="noclicked" />
```

I used obout button but  anormal button is also acceptable.
 The thing has been that when I use Gridrecordeventargs, no overload of delegate matches system handler. However when I use EventArgs, I cannot use gridrecordeventargs.So, can u let me know how to handle this?

Comment: Why not create a new `delegate`? Can you post your grid markup?

Comment: Hye I did not get you. Can u explain it in detail or some article that would help me?

Comment: You are trying to use this event handler for a grid event or a button event?

Comment: Is the Button present in the grid?

Comment: @Hasan: No this pops up when u try to insert duplicate record

Comment: @Bala: A normal button can also be used

Comment: You cannot use `GridRecordEventArgs` with a button click event handler because the button click event uses [`System.EventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx). You might be able define a command for the button and use OnRowCommand event, maybe.

Comment: @Bala: Is there any other way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Are the buttons placed inside or outside the Grid?
Do you need to access the data from the row containing the buttons (if the buttons are within the Grid)? If yes, then please check the following article:
http://www.obout.com/grid/KnowledgeBase.aspx?id=223

If the buttons are placed outside the Grid, you can simply go through the Rows collection of the Grid to access the data.

If you have text boxes (or other fields in the Grid) that are being displayed in view mode and you want to retrieve the data from those fields when clicking the buttons, use an approach similar to the one we used in the following sample:
http://www.obout.com/grid/commands/aspnet_commands_excel_style_full.aspx