# How to call a method that has parameters from a click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, methods

I have a method that gets a column value from an output gridview. How do I call this method in a button click event so that I can use the column value? Below is the method and button click event.

```
string mailAdd;
public void get_value(object sender, GridRecordEventArgs e)
{
    mailAdd = e.Record["emailAddress"].ToString();
}


protected void btnsendMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //call get_value here
}
```

Comment: [This previously asked question may help you.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349050/using-gridrecord-event-args

Comment: thank you Kenny for the link. the link uses a client side method that is not really clear to me . is there a way i can do this on server side and how

Comment: If you are going to do this all from server side, it seems to me that you must be able to embed enough information in your button to be able to construct a set of GridRecordEventArgs from the button's EventArgs.  If that is not possible, something client side is required.

Answer (score 0):

you cant ' because this method expect the EventArgs from the Sender which is the Grid object in your case , what I'd recommend is in 
Get_value set the e.record["emailAddress"].toString() to a session and call in button

```
public void get_value(object sender, GridRecordEventArgs e)
    {
        Session["emailAddress"]= e.Record["emailAddress"].ToString();
    }

protected void btnsendMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      //you can use this  
string _myEmail=Session["emailAddress"];
     }
```

regards

Comment: thanx King. but i get an error when i run the code. this is the error  " System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: add break point and see where its breaking?which line? maybe its the e.Record["emailAddress"]?

Answer (score -1):

is the part of the grid row? if yes then you should be using ItemCommand, if the button is separated from grid, then you may need to ascertain (dynamically) the row from which you want to read the email address. If you have the info, then you can easily access grid's content by row index and columnname, to get the email address, then rest is obvious.